# convert guid tostring in javascript .net

Tags: .net, javascript, guid, request.querystring

How do I convert guid to string in javascript. I am getting guid from the querystring, and m not able to process it as is. I have tried the following ways to do it but it doesnt seem to work.

```
var guid = {<%=Request.QueryString["Guid"]%>}.toString();
var guid = <%=Request.QueryString["Guid"]%>.toString();
var guid = (string)<%=Request.QueryString["Guid"]%>;
var guid = (string){<%=Request.QueryString["Guid"]%>};
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you give us an example url that you're testing with?

Comment: I would suggest adding more information on the 'Doesn't Seem To Work' part.

Comment: View the page source and look what is outputted. Normally shows you your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try quoting the string, this should work...

```
var guid = '<%=Request.QueryString["Guid"]%>';
```

Comment: What is the output?.. you could try: `var guid = '<%=Request.QueryString["Guid"].ToString()%>';` but it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just:

```
var guid = {<%=Request.QueryString["Guid"]%>}
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Are there any error messages?

Comment: In debug mode it was showing without any quotes or anything as if its an int or something. '<%=Request.QueryString["Guid"].ToString()%>' worked. Thank you!